# Unit test in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Does anyone uses this feature of VS2010 for C++ projects? If yes could this person give some links to tutorials or explain how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly use the VS unit test utilities for native c++ pojects. Basically you can unit test only .NET types. Of course, you can write unit tests for a C++/CLI (that's where `gcnew` and `^` come from) class or struct which wraps native c++ code... so, indirectly, yes, you can use VS to unit test native c++ code, you only need to provide appropriate .NET wrappers. This can be automatized to certain extent, but is still quite tedious. You also need to compile your native c++ project in a special way...

Answer (score 1):

Here's another interesting [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jsocha/archive/2010/11/19/writing-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-for-native-c.aspx) describing how to write Unit Tests in Visual Studio for Native C++.

Answer (score 0):

as requested

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243171.aspx

http://jendrikillner.wordpress.com/2009/05/06/unit-testing-c-with-the-visual-studio-unit-testing-framework/

a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fxl7zMzfFM

Comment: thanks any idea what '^' means and why is he using gcnew instead of new? It's not C++.

Comment: in the example video the test project is C++/CLR calling the COM interface of the C++ lib

Comment: but how does it explain use of ('^' - xor) and what gcnew has to do with C++?

Comment: In this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jsocha/archive/2010/11/19/writing-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-for-native-c.aspx) provided by @james below it says "Finally, if you want to test a string value returned by a function, you can do something like this:

Assert::AreEqual<String^>("Expected", gcnew String(pClass->StringValue());

Note in particular the use of gcnew, which creates a new instance of a managed class. Likewise, you’ll notice the ^ at the end of String in the AreEqual. This tells the compiler that we’re working with a pointer to a managed instance of type String."